# Change access/scope of C variable from static to global at compile time, without changing source code?

Tags: c, gcc, static

Let's say, in my C executable project, I use a C library to which I have source access - in fact, the .c files of the library get built as part of the build process for my C executable.

Then, let's say in some of the library .c files, let's say `exotic.c`, there is something like:

```c
static struct exotic_type all_exotic_array[NUM_EXOTIC_ITEMS][8];
```

... which the author of the library believes should remain hidden (ergo `static`) - but which, it turns out, I need a reference to in my code; therefore I'd like to make this variable's symbol publicly accessible.

So, in principle I could just erase the `static` keyword there and recompile - and I'd get the `all_exotic_array` as global. However, let's say I also do *not* want to change the source code of the library.

So in this context, I can intervene in the Makefile, when the individual library .c files get compiled. So:

- Is there a compilation switch, with which I could tell the compiler `gcc` (or linker `ld`?), while compiling `exotic.c`, something like: "*please ignore the `static` storage class specifier of the symbol `all_exotic_array`, and make it available globally*"?
- If not - is there any other action I could take (maybe after compilation of `exotic.c` but before linking my executable), to make the symbol `all_exotic_array` globally available?

I have seen

- [Access of static variable from one file to another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009246/access-of-static-variable-from-one-file-to-another-file?rq=1)
- [Renaming symbols at compile time without changing the code in a cross platform way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204836/renaming-symbols-at-compile-time-without-changing-the-code-in-a-cross-platform-w)
- [Access a global static variable from a .so file without modifying library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144957/access-a-global-static-variable-from-a-so-file-without-modifying-library)
- [Keep all exported symbols when creating a shared library from a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664759/keep-all-exported-symbols-when-creating-a-shared-library-from-a-static-library)

... which hint that there may be a possibility to do what I want, however I couldn't find exactly what to do in my use case.

Comment: According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484085/can-gcc-ignore-static-declaration-of-a-function), there is no way to make `gcc` ignore `static`.

Comment: During the build, copy the original library source file to a temporary file. Alter the temporary file. Compile the temporary file.

Comment: sdbbs, "but which, it turns out, I need a reference to in my code;" --> Hmmm, one step closer to the precipice.  Consider posting the real problem rather than a "how do I do x to solve (unstated) y" question.